UITableview Reorder - Customize shadow appearance

I tried modifying the shadow property of the cell's layer. But that did not work.
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
layer.shadowRadius = 8
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)
layer.masksToBounds = false

Also, I could not access the cell right after being lifted up.

Look into UITableViewCell dragStateDidChange.

@HangarRash it is not called at all. I also noticed in the view hierarchy that the UIShadowView used to create the shadow effect is a private property and could not be accessed.
